# ToggleClass using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, toggleclass

I'm trying to toggle a sidebar via toggling classes. In jQuery I had:

```
$("[data-toggle]").click(function () {
    var toggle_el = $(this).data("toggle");
    $(toggle_el).toggleClass("open-sidebar");
});
```

Wondering how I'd achieve the same thing with AngularJS

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-class` set to a variable:

```
ng-class="{'someClass' : scopeVar }"
```

And toggle `scopeVar` on a click:

```
$scope.toggle = function() { $scope.scopeVar = !$scope.scopeVar }
```